# ssrs multi column table data gets spanned accross columns and/or pages incorrectly

Tags: sql, reporting-services, formatting, reporting

In SSRS I built a report where a providers name, address, phone are listed in 3 columns on a page Grouped by State. Example Data:
[alt text http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/9062/providerlistingex.png](http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/9062/providerlistingex.png)

What I'm trying to do is prevent the data from spilling over into the next column or page. I want to just move the provider to the next column/page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the data presented in a Table control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from the result how you structured your report. Each address should be in a single table cell. Then I don't think you would see addresses being broken apart.

Comment: interesting idea I have them set as 4 different rows, I'll try formatting them in a single cell